# png showing in firefox/IE but not chrome

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-hosting

I'm making my first website and finally got everything hosted, but the images aren't showing in google chrome. I was amazed when it worked in IE because I thought they usually gave the most trouble.

[image: Left: firefox, Middle: IE, Right: chrome]

Here is the html where I input the images:

```
<th class="red-header"><p>Strength</p>
    <img src="./pictures/strength.png" alt="str" class="str">
</th>
<th class="blue-header"><p>Intelligence</p>
    <img src="./pictures/intelligence.png" alt="int" class="int">
</th>
<th class="green-header"><p>Dexterity</p>
    <img src="./pictures/dexterity.png" alt="dex" class="dex">
</th>
```

and

```
<th class="red-header"><p>Fire</p>
    <img src="./pictures/fire.png" alt="fire" class="fire">
</th>
<th class="blue-header"><p>Cold</p>
    <img src="./pictures/cold.png" alt="cold" class="cold">
</th>
<th class="yellow-header"><p>Lightning</p>
    <img src="./pictures/lightning.png" alt="lightning" class="lightning">
</th>
```

I couldn't find anything helpful in my searches. Please share any ideas you have or let me know what I can do to help you answer.

Comment: Open the console and check if the files return a 404. You did try hitting CTRL-F5 etc?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The website is hosted on Hostgator, the picture files are in the directory on their server, and it is showing on 2/3 browsers.

Comment: Oh my god ctrl-f5 worked. Why??

Comment: Updates the cache in the browser, now you know !

Comment: The ctrl-f5 worked, if you explain why in answer i'll accept it!

Comment: That makes sense why firefox/IE worked. I never use them so the cache was empty when I tried them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to speed up web browsing, browsers are designed to download web pages and their content, like images, and store them locally on your computer's hard drive in an area called "cache".

Browser cache contains records of every item you have viewed or downloaded while visiting your site, so when you visit the same page for a second time, the browser speeds up display time by loading the page locally from cache instead of downloading everything again.

When testing changes and new images etc. you sometimes want to get the data from the source again, and update the cache.

Hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> will most of the time give you the same page even if the content is changed *(depending on headers etc)*, because it may load the page from cache, while <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> forces a cache refresh, and will guarantee that if the content is changed, you will get the new content.